# Произношение латинских слов

Tags: фонетика

Известно, что в латинском (как и в современном итальянском, а также испанском) звук Л практически всегда мягкий - "ль". И, признаться, меня всегда несколько дергает, когда говорят, например, "ламбда", а не "лямбда" и т.д.
А также, если уже речь зашла о романских языках, в испанском удвоенное L читается как Й. Но по-русски эта удвоенная L все равно произносится, например, в слове "ла паэлья" (la paella) всесто "ля паэйя", хотя, слово Майорка (Mallorca) произновится так же, как и в оригинале.
Так как все-таки правильно: *ла* или *ля*, *й* или *л*?

Comment: Известно, что в латинском ...звук Л практически всегда мягкий - "ль" - Кому известно? Латинский язык - мертвый язык. Носителей нет. Восстановить произношение вряд ли возможно.

Answer (score 2):

Не являюсь специалистом по латинской фонетике, но произношение буквы L "всегда мягко", как пишут в некоторых справочниках, - это попытка приблизить латинское звучание к русскому. У нас  звуки [л] и [л'] противопоставлены, они выполняют смыслоразличительную функцию (являются фонемами). Сравните: лад [лат] и ляд [л'ат]. В латинском же языке оппозиции по твердости-мягкости нет. Меня учили, что звук [l] (как в латинском, так и в итальянском) - нечто среднее между наши твердым [л] и мягким [л']: не очень твердо, но и не слишком мягко. В итальянском языке, мягкость согласного L наблюдается в буквосочетании gli, которое в транскрипции передается как [ʎ] (палатальный, т.е. передненёбный звук,  схожий с русским [л'], только чуть более твердый). Об испанском языке ничего не могу сказать, поскольку не изучала его.

Comment: Не "приблизить к русскому", а, имхо, ввести некоторое единообразие. причем - ошибочное.

Answer (score 1):

А ничего, что "лямбда" - буква греческая? )))

Сначала про испанский. Я этого языка совсем не знаю, но по общему принципу могу сказать, что во-первых, заимствования не обязаны точно следовать фонетике оригинала, хотя топонимы следуют чаще, а во-вторых, более старые заимствования могут следовать историческому произношению. Сравните "бульон", но "буйонский" лес - из французского.
Ну и наконец, "испанский" язык - это на самом деле язык кастильский, у него много других дуалектов, я не уверен, что везде правила чтения подобных сочетаний следуют кастильской норме.

Вот в отнешении латинского языка - тут сложнее. Латинский язык существует (или существовал) в нескольких вариантах: классическая латынь, латынь плебейская (о ней мы почти ничего не знаем кроме того, что она сильно отличалась от классической), латынь средневековая (что-то вроде средневекового эсперанто) и, наконец, собственно латынь, т.е. современный вариант латыни средневековой. Говорить о единстве произношения не приходится, но в общем-то современная "международная" латынь требует твердого произношения L. В средневековом варианте наблюдались колебания, про классический вариант наверняка сказать ничего нельзя, скорее всего оно было полумягким как в современном английском, что на слух русским ухом воспринимается как твердое.
Кстати, наиболее близкий к классической латыни современный молдавский имеет выраженную твердую Л.